How to use multipart/form-data with requests session?
I want to send data with requests as form-data. I use the request's session. However, it still send the data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded form. I started a test servver with nc -kdl 8000.
import requests

import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1


session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
}

data = {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
}

response = session.post(
    "http://localhost:8000",
    data=data,
    headers=headers,
)

The output
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 27

field1=value1&field2=value2

However I want the followed output
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="delimiter12345"

--delimiter12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--delimiter12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--delimiter12345--

